# What are the ways to rename a file by referring to a text document?

Tags: php, rename, file-rename

I have duplicated one image file multiple times and then renamed it like this:

**Image files:**

```
x (1).jpg
x (2).jpg
x (3).jpg
...
```

I would like to rename these files, referring to a `.txt` document where I already stored the desired names for this files.

**One line takes one name:**

```
a.jpg
b.jpg 
c.jpg 
...
```

**My php-code so far:**

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 420; $i++) {
    rename("/folder1/folder2/x ($i).jpg", "/names.txt");
}
```

I don't know how to go on, because I think somehow it has to be specified that after every loop it should skip the line before.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP to do this in one step using [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) . All you need are (1) the original image file (2) the list of names you want in a file, one per line, and (3) a simple script to read the text file and create copies of the original file.

```
// first you need to open and read your names file line by line
$names_file = file("your_filenames.txt");
foreach($names_file as $line) {
  copy("path_to_original_image.jpg", $line);
  }
```

Comment: Warning: copy(sample_name_from_txt_file.jpg ): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\first\query.php on line 91

Comment: copy() takes two arguments. The first argument is the file that should be copied. The second argument is where the file should be copied TO. It looks like you may have left something out.

Comment: You used a comma instead of a period to concatenate the two parts of your second argument. The interpreter thinks you are trying to pass a third argument. Try this instead: `copy("filesystem/images/source.jpg", "filesystem/images/".$line);`

Comment: You need to concatenate the directory and `$line`, you're passing `$line` as the third argument now.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: *copy("filesystem/images/source.jpg", "filesystem/images/".$line);* doesn't work :/

Comment: Is there a specific error? Are your paths correct and relative to the path you are running the script from? Have you tried echoing $line to make sure the filenames are reading in correctly from the file?

Answer (score 1):

The [`file` method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) in php reads a file and inserts each line into an array. Therefore, you can try this:

```
$filenames = file("/names.txt");

for($i = 1; $i <= 420; $i++) {
    rename("/folder1/folder2/x ($i).jpg", $filenames[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially renaming all .jpg files to /names.txt here. If you need to load the names from a file, use `file('/names.txt')`. Then, you can use a for loop to iterate over the lines in that file.